# Date comparison using $filter not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date-comparison

I have an application in Angular JS and on one screen, there are 2 date pickers and there is a validation that FirstDate cannot be after SecondDate.

**Test case:**

```
FirstDate: '10/01/2014'
SecondDate: '04/01/2015'
```

**Condition:**

```
if( $filter('date')(FirstDate) > $filter('date')(SecondDate) )
  alert(FirstDate)
else
  alert(SecondDate)
```

**Desired Output:**

```
"SecondDate"
```

**Output:**

```
"FirstDate"
```

Can you please help what the issue is?
My guess is, instead of considering date, it is considering them as string.

Comment: 10 > 4 seems :), you must need to parse date as valid date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$filter('date') works with date object and converting it to string. So in you case you rather need to convert string to date object before you compare it

```
if( Date.parse(FirstDate) > Date.parse(SecondDate) )
  alert(FirstDate);
else
  alert(SecondDate);
```